# Restrict file search to ONE folder and it's subs

Tags: 12.10, unity, settings, zeitgeist, privacy

When I go to Settings > Privacy > Files (tab)

It provides me with the option to provide a list of folders:

> "Don't record activity in the following folders"

However, I'd like to be able to do the opposite:

> "Record activity ONLY in the following folders"

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: At the moment it is not possible.

**Long Answer**: The logging engine supports only blacklists. When it tries to log event, it checks it against all the blacklists. If any of them is matched, the event is dropped

---

**Workaround**: You can blacklist all the top level folders in your Home Directory and just leave out the one which you want to be logged